# hAxis label is cut off in Google chart

Tags: google-visualization

To track number of visitor comes through which website and do some analysis on the same. We are creating a column chart to show the analysis report in graphical form.

All the things are showing correctly on chart, but we are showing website name on haxis. As website name is too long like "www.google.com", www.facebook.com, this label are being cut off  on haxis.

Code to draw chart is given below:

```js
function createTodayChart(chartData){
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Sources');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Total Sales');

  for (var i in chartData){
    //alert(chartData[i][0]+'=>'+ parseInt(chartData[i][1]));
    data.addRow([chartData[i][0], parseInt(chartData[i][1])]);
  }

  var options = {
    legend: {position:'top'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Sources', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}, count: -1, viewWindowMode: 'pretty', slantedText: true},
    vAxis: {title: 'Total Sales (in USD)', titleTextStyle: {color: 'black'}, count: -1, format: '$#'},
    colors: ['#F1CA3A']
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('my_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);    
}
```

Data in chartData variable is in array form as:

```
var chartData = [];  
cartData.push('www.w3school.com', 106);  
cartData.push('www.google.com', 210);
```

Width and height of "my_div" are 350px and 300px respectively. We have also attached screen shot of this issue given below:

[image]

Can anyone help me that how can we prevent this cutting issue. Or, Is any method available in google chart API to prevent this?

Waiting for solution.

Comment: could you provide an example of the data / `chartData`?

Answer (score 41):

This is an always recurring issue in google visualization, in my opinion :( There are a few "tricks" one can experiment with : `chartArea` and `hAxis.textPosition`. Here is your code in a jsFiddle with the following chartData, reproducing the problem above :

```js
var chartData = [
    ['www.facebook.com', 45],
    ['http://www.google.com', 67],
    ['www.stackoverflow.com', 11]    
];
```

[image]

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/a6WYw/**

---

`chartArea` can be used to adjust the upper "padding" taking space from the legend / hAxis below along with the internal height of the bars (the chart itself without axis and legend). For example

```js
chartArea: {
   top: 55,
   height: '40%' 
}
```

Will shrink the chartArea, giving room for the legend on the hAxis.

[image]

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Swtv3/**

---

My personal favourite is to place the `hAxis` legend *inside* the chart by

```js
hAxis : { textPosition : 'in' }
```

This will honor both short and long descriptions, and does not make the chart looking too "weird" when there is a few very long strings.

[image]

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/7HBmX/**

---

As per comment - move the "in" labels outside the chart. There is to my knowledge no native way to do this, but we can always alter the `<svg>`. This *can* be a difficult task, but in this case we know that the only `<text>` elements who has the `text-anchor="middle"` attribute is the h-axis labels and the overall h-axis description. So

```
var y, labels =  document.querySelectorAll('[text-anchor="middle"]');
for (var i=0;i<labels.length-2;i++) { 
   y = parseInt(labels[i].getAttribute('y'));
   labels[i].setAttribute('y', y+30);
}
```

to move the labels outside the chart. demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/970opuu0/**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, but we want haxis label outside the chart and due to long label, we have to display label at some angle. The problem is, when label is cut off and there is no gap between haxis title "Source" and label. Due to which label are overlapping on haxis title.

Comment: @user2393886, "_The problem is, when label is cut off and there is no gap between haxis title "Source" and label._", I have updated the example, eg the `chartArea` solution - maybe it was not clear enough.  Now it demonstrates how to show all the text and have some space between labels / "source".

Comment: it is possible to display the text the same way as the "in" option, but outside the chart?

Comment: I'll answer myself: fixed it by changing the fontsize:  textStyle: {fontSize: 10},

Comment: @marimaf - have made an example of doing that (at the end of the answer). It can be done by moving the elements inside the `<svg>` around. Hope it helps.

Comment: @davidkonrad great hack with moving the 'in' outside, but very curious to know why the for loop has a -2?

Comment: @ChrisGoosey because the last two `<text>` items is the Y/X labels respectively.

Comment: This works well as written in the jsfiddle above. However, as soon as you add an `animation` option, this technique no longer works. I have replicated that in this - http://jsfiddle.net/ej5zd7y8/ . Why does `animation` make a difference?

Comment: @brendangibson You can postpone the replacement of labels until the animation has finished. You can use a `setTimeout` or perhaps better the `animationfinish` event. Updated fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ej5zd7y8/3/** not very elegant, but I dont think you can manipulate the chart *while* it is being animated.

Comment: Brilliant answer @davidkonrad!  It fixes my issue.